# I believe this shadow on the glass material is not normal, it follows my camera creating a weird effect, please help me fix it!

Tags: rendering, materials, transparency, eevee-render-engine, shadows

So basicly when I move the camera I get these shadows on the windows ( glass material).
The shadows follow the camera angle and i would like to remove them or fix them.

Im using Eevee. The shadows don´t appear in cycles render and i guess this would be a solution, but I would like to remove them on the eevee if possible.

[image: Angle1]
[image: RenderSettings]
[image: Angle2]
[image: Material1]
[image: Material2]

Answer (score 0):

Just wanna say that I was able to fix this by myself.
Seems like the problem was the refraction depth being set to 0.